# How to get a label value into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html code:

```
<div id="box">
    <div>
      <label for="text">Text 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="text">Text 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="text">Text 3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get all label in a div with id="box" so I use Jquery:

```
var container=$('div[id="box"]');
container.find('label[for="text"]').each(function(index){
    console.log("INDEX "+index);
});
```

The problem is that the jquery function print only one time "INDEX" 0. Anyone can help to print all label value?

Comment: How many `div[id="box"]`s do you have in your page?

Comment: `$("#box label").each(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see working Fiddle. Hope this will solve your problem

```js
function show(){
$("#box").find("label").each(function(){
  alert($(this).html());
  });}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <body>
<div id="box">
    <div>
      <label for="text">Text 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="text">Text 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="text">Text 3</label>
    </div>
</div>
   <input type="button" value="Show" onclick="return show();">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone can help to print all label value?

try

```
$('#box').find('label[for="text"]').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all labels directly.

```
$("#box label").each(function(index){
    console.log("INDEX "+index);
});
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2xs86bcr/1/).